# Page executing non-ajax call JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, tomcat6, ajax4jsf

I'm using Jsf 2.0, and trying to make a page that when a button is clicked it will hide one panel and show another one.

This first step is working, but in the second panel there is a button "back" that should do the same thing changing the panels.

So, the first step works and call the second with ajax, no problem. When I click on the "back" button the whole page is rendered again (You can see in the chrome navigator top the page loading).

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich" xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j" xmlns:ajax="https://ajax4jsf.dev.java.net/ajax" xmlns:cf="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
<ui:composition>

        <ui:include src="/composition/filtros.html" />
        <ui:include src="/composition/resumo.html" />


</ui:composition>
</html>
```

filtros.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich" xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j" xmlns:ajax="https://ajax4jsf.dev.java.net/ajax" xmlns:cf="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
<ui:composition>

    <a4j:outputPanel styleClass="#{not buscador.mostrarResumo ? 'show':'hide'}" ajaxRendered="true">
        <rich:collapsiblePanel header="Filtrar Mailing" switchType="client">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" width="100%" columnClasses="width-20-per" rowClasses="grid-row-odd, grid-row-even,">
                <h:outputLabel value="Campanha Selecionada:" styleClass="campanhaSelected" />
                <h:inputText value="#{buscador.campanha}" readonly="true" styleClass="inputCampanhaSelected" />
            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:form id="formBusca">

                <a4j:commandButton action="#{buscador.resumir(true)}" value="Adicionar"  />
                <rich:messages ajaxRendered="true"></rich:messages>
            </h:form>
        </rich:collapsiblePanel>
    </a4j:outputPanel>

</ui:composition>
</html>
```

resumo.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich" xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j" xmlns:ajax="https://ajax4jsf.dev.java.net/ajax" xmlns:cf="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
<ui:composition>

    <a4j:outputPanel styleClass="#{buscador.mostrarResumo ? 'show':'hide'}" ajaxRendered="true">

            <rich:collapsiblePanel header="Resumo" switchType="client">
            <h:form id="teste">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" width="100%" columnClasses="width-20-per" rowClasses="grid-row-odd, grid-row-even,">
                    <h:outputLabel value="Campanha Selecionada:" styleClass="campanhaSelected" />
                    <h:inputText value="#{buscador.campanha}" readonly="true" styleClass="inputCampanhaSelected" />
                </h:panelGrid>

                <a4j:commandButton action="#{buscador.buscar}" value="Confirmar" />
                <a4j:commandButton action="#{buscador.resumir(false)}" value="Voltar" /> //<------ here is the problem.

            </h:form>
        </rich:collapsiblePanel>
    </a4j:outputPanel>

</ui:composition>
</html>
```

CBuscador.java

```
    @ManagedBean(name = "buscador")
    @ViewScoped
    public class CBuscador implements Serializable {

//...some stuff

    public void resumir(boolean show) {
            if (show) {
                if (validarBusca()) {
                    url = prepararUrl();
                    mostrarResumo = true;

                } else {
                    FacesMessage facesMsg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, null, "Error message.");
                    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, facesMsg);
                }

            }else{
                mostrarResumo = false;

            }
        }
//some stuff...
}
```

Comment: I never used this component but have you tried with ` switchType="ajax"` ?

Comment: What about `render` attribute? Add `id` attribute for `outputPanel` (for example id="panelName") and use `<a4j:commandButton action="#{buscador.resumir(false)}" value="Voltar" render="panelName" />`.

Comment: I tried both. It only worked moving <h:form id="teste"> outside of the panel.

Comment: ajax calls tend to fail whenever you render/rerender an `h:form`. you might want to use a single `h:form` with attribute `prependId="false"`, containing the `ui:include`s in your master page. then change current `h:form`s ("formBusca" and "teste") to `h:panelGroup`s, and add `execute="formBusca"` and `execute="teste"` to the related `a4j:commandButton`s. that should work.